# Where can I host a script to run continuously?

Tags: cron, server

I am planning out a script that I would like to write that will check a website everyday at midnight and do what is needed based off the users input. I will be posting this script online so other people can use it.

However, I want the script to be able to continue running even when the users computer is off. Is there some place (I/the user) can host the script so that even when I/they turn off their computer it continues to run?

The immediate idea that comes to my head or hosting it on a server of some sort. Is that possible?

I have also been reading about cron. However, it appears that will stop working after the user has turned off their computer.

Any tips or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, cron stops running when you turn off the computer. Everything stops running when there is no power. One option for persistent computing is to run a EC2 instance on Amazon Web Services. There is one instance type that is free (up to a point I believe). Other cloud computing services such as MS Azure are also an option.

Comment: If I setup an EC2 instance or MS Azure would other users be able to user it without having to set it up?

Comment: @joe If you gave them access then yes. A better solution would be to provide them the script and let them use their own VM's. You should look into using Docker for that. It might be a little heavy-weight for just a single script though.

Comment: I have been looking into learning about Docker so maybe I will just for the experience. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

when the computer off nothing will happen, and no scripts will be executed.

to execute a script everyday at midnight CRON is your way.

usually this kind of scripts run on servers that stay running all the time.

Comment: Isn't CRON just a tool I would use in my script? So if my computer was off at midnight it wouldn't run.

Comment: of course this is your computer is on, there is no way to execute anything on an computer powered of. and as i mention script are usually executed on servers that stay running always